# The colours and fonts automatically changes on shared excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, microsoft-excel-2016, colors

We use a shared document to import data. We have a lot of different colours and informations on it, which is really important it stays that way, it is updated 1000x per day between 30 people.

However lately when someone updates it the colour of the text in the cell changes automatically to one colour, there is usually between 1-3 different colours per cells. Some cells also change font when clicking on it then back to normal when we click on another cell. We have tried to create new file with new cells but nothing works.

Example of the font change:

[image: example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you other people edit the Workbook? From web or locally shard folder?